complex migrations with moving data
I have asp .net core application. I would like to split table with data into the more parts and migrate some data from one table into the new one. Is there a way how to do that?
Before:
table_a
-------
id
cola1
cola2
moved_col  <--- This column must be moved into new table.

After:
table_a
-------
id
table_b_id
cola1
cola2

table_b
-------
id
colb1
colb2
moved_col  <--- This column must be moved into new table.


Create table_b
Add columt table_b_id into table_a
Move data from moved_col into table_b and connect new table_b ids into records in table_b
Remove moved_col from table_a

In Ruby On Rails migration is easy to achieve it, but I don't know how to do it correct way in Asp Net Core.

In Ruby On Rails migration is easy to achieve it - can you show this magic migration? Here it is not possible to do that without SQL.

It is need to execute sql, use reader and iterate items from table_a and execute sql inserts on table_b. So I need execute sql, use reader and iterate it in the migration... In RoR is it possible, but in Asp Net Core I am not sure.

use reader and iterate items... - worst idea ever, sql can do that much faster. In EF Core create 3 migrations: 1) create table table_b 2) Execute SQL INSERT INTO SELECT 3) Drop column moved_col  from table_a.
